# Sun Broadband Wireless and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

Good day!

I recently installed 12.04. I am having a hard time connecting to the Internet using my Sun Broadband Wireless. I installed the 64-bit version. I am from the Philippines.

When I plug in my USB stick, it does not show up on the Network Manager/ no new connection can be detected. I try to edit it using Edit Connections but still to no avail.

I have tried doing these steps from [kenji08](http://kenji08.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/installing-sun-broadband-huawei-e160-in-lucid/), [kartonista](http://www.kartonista.com/tech/configure-sun-wireless-broadband-in-ubuntu-netbook-edition-lucid-lynx.html), and from [review-ninja](http://www.review-ninja.com/2009/05/huawei-e160-and-ubuntu-e160-linux-howto.html) (for this one, I can't seem to get pass the first step.)

I hope those information can help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a work around for it. You may want to check it out [here](http://filesinbinary.com/how-to-set-up-smart-bro-globe-tattoo-and-sun-broadband-in-ubuntu-linux/).

Though the call and text features are not available in the Linux platform. I'm currently using a smart broadband prepaid so what I do is insert the SIM on a phone and register it from there.

Comment: his does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.